# Does Low Temperature Attract Negatively Charged Particles?

Tags: electricity, temperature, lightning, freezing

I'm studying the effects of temperature in producing electricity like in clouds that produces lightning. Since dark clouds during a thunderstorm is below freezing point, it attracts negatively charged particles, then producing lightning when positively charged particles meet with the negatively charged particles in the cloud.

So, the question is does temperature (like below freezing point), attracts negatively charged particles that helps produces lightning? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thunderstorm clouds ( Cummulonimbus calvus/inca/capillatus ) have complex charge related structure. The top and the bottom is positively charged, the middle negatively.This is related to GC+ and GC- discharges, with the former less frequent, longer and mightier ( up 10 km long, up to 1 billion volts )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Temperature is a statistical](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temper.html#targetText=Temperature%20Scales,-The%20Celsius%2C%20Kelvin&targetText=The%20freezing%20point%20of%20water,%C2%B0C%20are%20precise%20enough.) measure, it depends on ensembles of particles  and provides context for chemical interactions.

[image: tempera]

If the little balls in the picture represent molecules of air, there is no way for "temperature" to interact individually with the particles. Certainly attract and repulse electromagnetically has no meaning attributed to temperature.

Off hand one would expect  that with smaller kinetic energy less electrons will come off in interactions than with higher kinetic energy molecules.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since less electrons will come off, does that also mean that it will also gain electrons in smaller kinetic energy?

Comment: Yes, there will be less energy for friction to give off electrons. And do not forget, when the electrons are freed the molecules become postively charged ions. A more complicated model is needed to explain how clouds get charged https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/why-do-clouds-get-electrically-charged-564915#targetText=The%20water%20molecules%20inadvertently%20will%20collide%20with%20each%20other%2C%20rub,is%20positively%20charged%20as%20well.

Comment: The link you gave me, helped a lot. Thanks again, and God bless.